# iOS: display horizontal list whose elements vary in width

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have seen in several apps that they have a scrollable  horizontal list of items and each one has a different  width.
 How can that be achieved?
It seems like I could use a collection view but that would have a lot of overhead that is unnecessary.
Perhaps what I need is a horizontal stack view  inside of a scroll  view?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. Try using a Horizontal `UIStackView` embedded in a `UIScrollView` ... then come back and ask specific questions if you have trouble.

Comment: Hi mech my idea was to just put a stack (terrible name) view inside a scroll view to simplify things. Collection view is too much of an overkill IMHO